# Convert binary string to binary or decimal value

Tags: r, binary, typeconverter, valueconverter, bitconverter

Is there any function to convert binary string into binary or decimal value?

If I have a binary string `000101`, what should I do to convert it into `5`?

Comment: Which Language? This is a very basic functionality and you can write your own function for it..

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet - OP tagged the question [tag:r]; so I guess this concerns  the language [R](http://www.r-project.org/)

Comment: I know that I could write my own function.... the thing is if there is a simpler way to do it, I want to know it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use the `packBits` function (in the `base` package). Bear in mind that this function requires very specific input.

```
(yy <- intToBits(5))
#  [1] 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
# [26] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
# Note that there are 32 bits and the order is reversed from your example

class(yy)
[1] "raw"

packBits(yy, "integer")
# [1] 5
```

There is also the `strtoi` function (also in the `base` package):

```
strtoi("00000001001100110000010110110111", base = 2)
# [1] 20121015

strtoi("000101", base = 2)
# [1] 5
```

Comment: @LifeWorks, I had forgotten about the `strtoi` function; please see the edit.

Comment: `strtoi` can only convert binaries up to a decimal value of 2147483647 as its output is an integer and this is is the maximum integer value allowed by R (see `.Machine$integer.max`). In most cases, this limit should be largely sufficient. In some cases, such as converting bit64 numbers to decimal, you will run into problems. In that case Julius Vainora's answer does the trick as the output will be of type numeric.

Answer (score 22):

Here is what you can try:

```
binStr <- "00000001001100110000010110110111" # 20121015
(binNum <- 00000001001100110000010110110111) # 20121015
[1] 1.0011e+24
binVec <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1) # 2670721
shortBin <- 10011010010 # 1234
BinToDec <- function(x) 
    sum(2^(which(rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "")) == 1))-1))
BinToDec(binStr)
[1] 20121015
BinToDec(binNum)
[1] 576528
BinToDec(binVec)
[1] 2670721
BinToDec(shortBin)
[1] 1234
```

That is, you can input both strings (because of `as.character()`) and numeric binary values  but there are some problems with large numbers like `binNum`. As I understand you also want to convert binary string to numeric binary values, but unfortunately there is no such data type at least in base R.

**Edit:** Now `BinToDec` also accepts binary vectors, which might be a solution for large numbers. Function `digitsBase()` from package `sfsmisc` returns such a vector:

```
(vec <- digitsBase(5, base= 2, 10))
Class 'basedInt'(base = 2) [1:1]
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    0
[10,]    1
BinToDec(vec)
[1] 5
```

Finally, another possibility is package `compositions` , for example:

```
(x <- unbinary("10101010"))
[1] 170
(y <- binary(x))
[1] "10101010"
```

Answer (score 17):

```
base::strtoi(binary_string, base = 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

This function calculates the decimal version with a flexible base. Base equals 2 is binary, etc. This should work up until a base of 10.

```
base2decimal = function(base_number, base = 2) {
  split_base = strsplit(as.character(base_number), split = "")
  return(sapply(split_base, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * base^(rev(seq_along(x) - 1)))))
}
> base2decimal(c("000101", "00000001001100110000010110110111"))
[1]        5 20121015
```

Comment: Could this be simplified: if instead of character vector like `c("000101", "00000001001100110000010110110111")` we have just one string like `"00000001001100110000010110110111"` then is it possible to drop `sapply` above? What is the most simplified code in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you have binary **string**, all of the prior answers are great. I often find myself in situations where I want to encode a combination of binary vectors. The logic of translating from a combination of 0's and 1's to an integer is always the same:

```
bincount <- function(B, base=2) { return(B %*% base^seq(0,ncol(B)-1)) }
```

Where B is a matrix, and each column is a binary vector.

Example:

```
isBig <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
isRed <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
B = cbind(isBig,isRed)
bincount(B)
# 0 1 2 3
```