# R, extract duplicated values from row and column, then convert from binary to integer

Tags: r, binary, extract, tostring

I have a table (no header) in R:

1  1  1  0  0
 1  1  1  0  0
0  0  0  1  1

What I want to do is extract continuous 1s from every row and column to later on make a string with these 1s and finally convert the string to an integer from binary.

Example, say I extract the continuous 1s from row 1 -> 1 1 1, then I make a string from these 1s, and finally convert this string which is a binary value to a n integer, the outcome should be 7.

Thank you.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12892348/1315767) can be a useful starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that you just have contiguous 1s with no 1s elsewhere, you can do something like this:

```
2 ^ rowSums(tab) - 1
```

For example:

```
tab <- as.table(matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1), nrow = 3, byrow = T))
2 ^ rowSums(tab) - 1
# A B C
# 7 7 3
```

If you do not have this contiguity assumption, us the run-length encoding:

```
-1 + 2 ^ apply(tab, 1, function(x) max(rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values == 1]))
```

Then the example is

```
tab <- as.table(matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1), nrow = 3, byrow = T))

#   A B C D E F
# A 0 1 1 1 0 0
# B 0 1 1 1 0 0
# C 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

and the above again yields

```
# A B C
# 7 7 3
```