# Removing space between numeric values in R

Tags: r

My list consist values as shown.

```
Mylist:
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

I need to convert this binary values to decimal. I am using `BinToDec()` function. But here values are space separated. How to get the values like 111011, 000010 etc in that list. I have tried with `gsub`, but it removes spaces in string. Thanks!

Comment: make a reproducible example with dput() - please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `gsub` with `lapply` to remove all whitespace:

```
BinToDec <- function(x) 
    sum(2^(which(rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "")) == 1))-1))

lst <- list("1 1 1 0 1 1", "0 0 0 0 1 0", "0 0 0 0 1 0")
unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) BinToDec(gsub("\\s+", "", x))))

[1] 59  2  2
```

I took the above `BinToDec` function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892348/convert-binary-string-to-binary-or-decimal-value), which maybe is also where you saw it.

**Edit:**

If you actually have a list of integer vectors, then use this option:

```
lst <- list(c(1,1,1,0,1,1), c(0,0,0,0,1,0), c(0,0,0,0,1,0))
unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) BinToDec(paste(as.character(x), collapse=""))))

[1] 59  2  2
```

### Demo

Comment: It works for the conversion, But here `lst <- list("1 1 1 0 1 1", "0 0 0 0 1 0", "0 0 0 0 1 0")`  is given manually. The list 'Mylist' directly taken to this. So i tried `as.character` conversion. it converts like this. ( "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "1" ). So that i am getting decimal values like  `4472900      64      64`  . This is not the expeccted one.

Comment: @9113303 Why are you using `as.character`?  I don't understand your comment.  Do you have a list of factors?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's a list of integer vectors and OP is saying it's space separated because that's what it looks like when you print it.

Comment: @duckmayr I added a solution in case you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.`as.numeric(paste(as.character(Mylist[[i]]),collapse = ""))` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Package (StringR)

The code below allows to find certain character and remove or replace

Code 
str_replace_all(x, " ", "")

related to you

str_replace_all(list, " ", "")

Explanation

str_replace_all(Dataset, "*character you are looking up* ", "*replacement character* ")

If only for a certain row be sure to do the following

str_replace_all(Dataset$Row, "*character you are looking up* ", "*replacement character* ")